# Restructure complex nested array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this:

```
var my_array= [
    [2, [[9, 10]]],
    [5, [[10, 11]]],
    [4, [[11, 9]]],
    [1, [[19, 2], [41, 10]]],
    [7, [[17, 3]]],
    [0, [[11, 4], [18, 5]]]
]
```

The arrays in `my_array` includes another two arrays (the first is not that necessary, but looking at the second (`myarray[1]` : This array includes different x/y-coordinates `[18, 4]`)

I'd like to get as result another array that looks like this (explanation below):

```
var result_array= [
    [ [2, [9, 10]], [5, [10, 11]], [4, [11, 9]], [0, [11, 4]] ],
    [ [1, [19, 2]],  [0, [18, 5]] , [7, [17, 3]] ],    
    [ [1, [41, 10]] ]
]
```

Arrays are now sorted by their x-values (`[9, 10]` --> x-value: `9`)  and grouped in new arrays. The difference between the x-values can be, lets say,  +/- 2 indexes (x-values 7,8,**9**,10,11) could be in one group.

I have no idea how to code this; this is what I have so far:

```js
var my_array= [
        [2, [[9, 10]]],
        [5, [[10, 11]]],
        [4, [[11, 9]]],
        [1, [[19, 2], [41, 10]]],
        [7, [[17, 3]]],
        [0, [[11, 4], [18, 5]]]
    ]

function sortArray(array) {
  var difference = 2,
    result = '';

  var array_sorted = [];
    array.forEach(function(a) {
     a[1].forEach(function(b) {
       array_sorted.push([b[0],b[1],a[0]]);
    })
  })
  array_sorted = array_sorted.sort(function(a,b) {return a[0]-b[0]});
  
  array_sorted.forEach(function(a) {
    if (a[0] > difference) {
    difference = a[0];
     array_sorted.push(array_group); array_group = [];}
     array_group.push([a]);
  })

  return array_sorted;
}

console.log(sortArray(my_array));
```

---

**Edit**: One point I forgot to mention, is that the `y-value difference` of the coordinates that should be grouped should not be bigger than `1`. Look at the example below:

`(x: 3, y:1),(x: 1, y:2),(x: 2, y:3),(x: 4, y:4)` --> `not (x: 4, y:41)`

**Edit 2**:

```
var my_array= [
    [2, [[9, 10]]],
    [5, [[10, 11]]],
    [4, [[11, 9]]],
    [1, [[19, 2], [41, 10]]],   
    [7, [[17, 3]]],
    [0, [[11, 4], [18, 5]]]
]

var result_array= [
    [ [2, [9, 10]], [5, [10, 11]], [4, [11, 9]] ], // line 1
    [ [0, [11, 4]] ],                              // line 2 
    [ [1, [19, 2]] ],                              // line 3
    [ [7, [17, 3]] ],                              // line 4 
    [ [0, [18, 5]] ],                              // line 5 
    [ [1, [41, 10]] ]                              // line 6 
]
```

If you have a look at line 1 & line & line 2: The x values (line2: '11' & line 1: '9','10','9' would match perfectly together. Now I also want to separate the y-values like in the example I've edited above. 
--> Even if the `x-values match together`, they should just be grouped into new arrays if there `y-values match together`.

Y-value match means, that there is something like a row --> 
 (x: 2, **y:4**),(x: 1, **y:5**), (x: 2, **y:6**), (x: 2, **y:7**) and not values like (x: 4, **y:42**)

I hope my edit made it easier to understand my thoughts..

Thanks in advance, Jonas

Comment: ... Really don't know what to answer to such a comment @mplungjan

Comment: You made a snippet. The snippet immediately shows an error in `return b[1][0] - b[1][0]` which you need to solve before continuing, I would think

Comment: "The difference between the x-values can be, lets say, +/- 2 indexes"  I don't think this is a clear enough specification to be codeable.  If you had x values of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, and 10, how would that be grouped?

Comment: @DanielBeck Every time from the first onwards `[2, [[9, 10]]]` (first array --> xValue: 9)

Comment: "Every time from the first onwards" well that's my point; say for example your data contained x values of 1...10, if you started from the first one that would lead to (1,2,3) being grouped together, as 1 +/-2; then (4,5,6); (7,8,9); (10).  But if you're aiming for a minimum number of groups, you'd want (1..5), (6..10) -- this would be more complicated to code, because it requires looking at the whole set of x-values to determine how best to group them, instead of just starting with the first value...

Comment: Your completely right, but the first (easier) solution is fine. Just checking the first element +-2 indexes is a good way. @DanielBeck

Comment: @Jonas0000 Could you please update your example to clarify what you actually mean after the edit? I think that it is possible to make a slight modification into my solution to fit this change.

Comment: Hey, I've made an edit to my question above. Thanks @mpasko256

Comment: the edit spoils the answers and now it's a complete new question. so please roll back and ask another question for the newer request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit: formatting and code style**

**Edit2: Response to original question edits**

```js
var my_array= [
  [2, [[9, 10]]],
  [5, [[10, 11]]],
  [4, [[11, 9]]],
  [1, [[19, 2], [41, 10]]],   
  [7, [[17, 3]]],
  [0, [[11, 4], [18, 5]]]
]

    var xdifference = 2;
    var ydifference = 1;

  function split(input_array) {
    var splitted = [];

    input_array.forEach(function (item) {
      var coordinates = item[1];
      coordinates.forEach(function (coordinate) {
        splitted.push([item[0], coordinate]);
      });
    });
    return splitted;
  }

  function getXValueOf(item) {
    return item[1][0];
  }

  function getYValueOf(item) {
    return item[1][1];
  }

  function divideIntoHeaps(sorted_array) {
    var heaps = [];
    function findMatchingHeap(item) {
       var matching = heaps.find(function (heap) {
         return heap.every(function (itemOfHeap) {
           var xMatches = Math.abs(getXValueOf(item) - getXValueOf(itemOfHeap)) <= xdifference+1;
           var yMatches = Math.abs(getYValueOf(item) - getYValueOf(itemOfHeap)) <= ydifference+1;
           return xMatches && yMatches;
         });
       });
       return matching;
    }
    function allocate(item) {
      if (heaps.length == 0) {
        heaps.push([item]);
      } else {
        var matchingHeap = findMatchingHeap(item);
        if (matchingHeap !== undefined) {
          matchingHeap.push(item);
        } else {
          heaps.push([item]);
        }
      }
    }
    sorted_array.forEach(allocate);
    return heaps;
  }

  function sortArray(my_array) {
    var splitted = split(my_array);
    var result = divideIntoHeaps(splitted);
    return result;
  }
  
  var result = sortArray(my_array);
  result.forEach( function (row) {
     console.log(JSON.stringify(row));
  });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Ok tried to get your solution for a long time, and I think I just got your thoughts right now. Looks fine, thanks a lot <3

Comment: I have updated the code but have got a result, that items starting with 1 and 7 landed in the same heap. If their x difference is 2 and y is 1, should it be fine?

Answer (score 0):

If we name the parts of your input `[[z,[[x,y],[x,y]],...]`, then this code flattens that into `[[x,y,z],...]`, sorts by `x`, then chunks that back up into groups:

```js
var my_array= [
    [2, [[9, 10]]],
    [5, [[10, 11]]],
    [4, [[11, 9]]],
    [1, [[19, 2], [41, 10]]],
    [7, [[17, 3]]],
    [0, [[11, 4], [18, 5]]]
]

var rearrange = function(arr) {
  // flatten the input structure into [[x,y,z], [x,y,z]]:
  var simpler = [];
  arr.forEach(function(row) {
    row[1].forEach(function(pair) {
      simpler.push([pair[0],pair[1],row[0]]);
    })
  });
  // sort by x:
  simpler = simpler.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a[0]-b[0]
  });
  // console.log(simpler);
  // Now group by x±2, into [ [z,[x,y]],[z,[x,y]] ]
  var output = [];
  var group = [];
  var latestX=simpler[0][0];
  simpler.forEach(function(row) {
    if (row[0] > latestX + 5) {
      // start a new group
      latestX = row[0];
      if (group.length > 0) {
        output.push(group);
        group = [];
      }
    }
    group.push([row[2],[row[0],row[1]]]);  
  });
  output.push(group); // catch the last group
  return output;

}
console.log(rearrange(my_array));
```

Comment: Your solution looks absolutely fine. Thanks a lot Daniel. If you like help me once more, look at my edit above. Thanks in advance, Greetings

Comment: That's... a pretty substantial change to the question.

Comment: You're completely right Daniel. It's ok, I will take a look on my own later if you no longer feel like it. However, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could a single point and check all groups if the value are in the wanted range of a node of a group. If not in any group, generate a new group and store the point. Proceed until no more point are available.

```js
var array = [[2, [[9, 10]]], [5, [[10, 11]]], [4, [[11, 9]]], [1, [[19, 2], [41, 10]]], [7, [[17, 3]]], [0, [[11, 4], [18, 5]]]],
    normalized = array.reduce(function (r, a) {
        return r.concat(a[1].map(function (b) { return [a[0], b]; }));
    }, []),
    grouped = [],
    i, j, k,
    updated;

loop: while (normalized.length) {
    if (!updated) {
        grouped.push([normalized.shift()]);
    }
    updated = false;
    for (i = 0; i < normalized.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < grouped.length; j++) {
            for (k = 0; k < grouped[j].length; k++) {
                if (Math.abs(normalized[i][1][0] - grouped[j][k][1][0]) <= 2 && Math.abs(normalized[i][1][1] - grouped[j][k][1][1]) <= 1) {
                    grouped[j].push(normalized.splice(i, 1)[0]);
                    updated = true;
                    continue loop;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

console.log(grouped.map(function (a) { return JSON.stringify(a); }));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Older Version for just one dimenstion.

You could take a straight forward approach by

- normalize values,
- sorting values,
- grouping where the delta is smaller or equal to two.

```js
var array = [[2, [[9, 10]]], [5, [[10, 11]]], [4, [[11, 9]]], [1, [[19, 2], [41, 10]]], [7, [[17, 3]]], [0, [[11, 4], [18, 5]]]],
    grouped = array
        .reduce(function (r, a) {
            return r.concat(a[1].map(function (b) { return [a[0], b]; }));
        }, [])
        .sort(function (a, b) {
            return a[1][0] - b[1][0];
        })
        .reduce(function (r, a, i, aa) {
            if (aa[i - 1] && a[1][0] - aa[i - 1][1][0] <= 2) {
                r[r.length - 1].push(a);
            } else {
                r.push([a]);
            }
            return r;
        }, []);

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```