# Javascript: Group array into ascending-order

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array like this:

```
var my_array = [[6, 2], [7, 3], [9, 4], [9, 6], [3, 7]]
```

... and I'd like to sort the array in different groups like below:

```
var result = [ [6, 2], [7, 3], [9, 4] ], 
             [ [9, 6], [3, 7] ]
```

So as you can see the sort method should group all arrays their `array[1]` values are matching together (like an ascending row)

SO the values in the example above `result[0][1]` --> **2**, `result[1][1]` --> **3**, `result[0][3]` --> **4** are matching together.

Also the group `result[1][0]` --> **6** and `result[1][1]` --> **7** are matching together.

BTW: The my_array - array is already sorted, so that `my_array[x][1] <= my_array[x+1][1]`.

I have no clue how to code this, so this is all what I got till now:

```js
var my_array = [[6, 2], [7, 3], [9, 4], [9, 6], [3, 7]] 


function sort_array(array) {
  var group=[];
  for (var i=array[0][1]; i<3; i++) {
   if (array[i+1][1] == i) {
    group.push(array[i+1])
   }
   else {
    
   }
  }
  return group;

}


console.log(sort_array(my_array));
```

Comment: jonas is that you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47598379/restructure-complex-nested-array

Comment: Hey @NinaScholz, thanks for your help but the question does not really match to my problem. The user you refer to tried to sort an complex array `... however, I can not really get the sense...,` but I just want to sort an array in the right order.

Comment: This isn't a sort problem.  It's a grouping problem.  You're not taking items and putting them in a different order.  You are changing up the data model.

Comment: Thats true, ok maybe your right it's not really sorting arrays @Taplar.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of your request;

1. Take a given array of two item arrays (already sorted by item 2)
2. group the two item arrays by the sequential item 2's (split them when you encounter a missing int).
3. return the result.

```js
var my_array = [[6, 2], [7, 3], [9, 4], [9, 6], [3, 7]] 


function sort_array(array) {
  var results = [];
  var tmp = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    tmp.push(array[i]);
    if(i== array.length -1 || array[i][1] != (array[i+1][1]-1)){
      results.push(tmp);
      tmp = [];
    }
  } 
  
  return results;
}


console.log(sort_array(my_array));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the grouping using recursion, it basically compares the current and the next number, if the next number is consecutive it will continue to call itself, if it's not consecutive it will add a new group then call itself until there is no next value.

```js
"use strict" // this will allow tail call recursion in modern browsers

const my_array = [[5, 0], [6, 2], [7, 3], [9, 4], [9, 6], [3, 7], [4, 10]] 

function groupConsecutiveYs([curr, ...rest], acc = [[]]) {
  const next = rest[0]
  // add to current group
  acc[acc.length - 1].push(curr)

  if (typeof next === 'undefined') // we are done return the accumulator
    return acc

  // if next is not consecutive add another grouping
  if (curr[1] !== next[1] - 1)
    acc.push([])
  
  // call recursive function again
  return groupConsecutiveYs(rest, acc)
}

console.log(
  groupConsecutiveYs(my_array)
)
```

```html
<script src="https://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/KyQQmL.js?concise=true"></script>
```